# Python pygeocoder error for version 1.2.1

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the code I am trying to run in python 2.6

```
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
results = Geocoder.geocode("Ireland")
print(results[0].coordinates)
```

I have installed pygeocoder from link (http://code.xster.net/pygeocoder/wiki/Home) on my windows machine.

While trying to run it gives error :

```
C:\work>TestGeoCode.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\work\TestGeoCode.py", line 2, in <module>
results = Geocoder.geocode("Ireland")
File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\pygeocoder-1.2.1-py2.6.egg\pygeocoder.py",
line 160, in geocode
return GeocoderResult(Geocoder.get_data(params=params))
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class GeocoderResult with abstract methods
__next__
```

While on my ubuntu machine it is working fine.

Could any one please tell me why this error comes up?

Thanks
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Geocoder.geocode("[Town], [Country]")`

Comment: There code from example is work it ? from pygeocoder import Geocoder
results = Geocoder.geocode("Tian'anmen, Beijing")
print(results[0].coordinates)

Comment: I have already tried their examples. But this problem still persists. I just don not able what this error message trying to say.

Comment: Different version of python you are used ? What version of Windows and Linux are used ?

Comment: On window python version is 2.6 and in ubuntu version is 2.7.

Comment: Update the version of python on Windows to 2.7.x

Comment: Do you still have a problem?